# Hibernate - Collection not populating all children

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, criteria, grails-orm

I have been having a very weird issue in hibernate.

We are using Grails and GORM to develop an application.

The behavior is the following.
Lets assume I have a relationship Department -> Employees.
Basically lets suppose I have Dept.id=1 which have 3 employees and Dept.id=2 which have 5 employees.

We are trying to create a query like.
Retrieve all the departments where employee.id = X.

Let it be via join/criteria or whatever we get the query working, but the only child populated in the collection is the employee that match the id = X.

It doesnt matter if I do a getSize or whatever, the collection never gets populated with the real data, I mean, the other 3 or 4 employees.

This is a very weird issue and to be honest, I never experienced it in the past.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In order to help you, it would help us to see the HQL query you are executing, and also the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to use Hibernate.initialise(proxy)?

Initialise method inits the proxy object.

Answer (score 0):

To see what's going on, follow these steps:

1. [Configure Hibernate](http://fillinginthegaps.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/how-to-show-sql-queries-in-grails/) to output the SQL it generates.  See what its actually querying.
2. If that doesn't help, up the server logging to DEBUG, and see what Hibernate spits out.
3. If that still doesn't help, attach the Hibernate source to Eclipse and step debug.